# raspberry pi pico ejects automatically after trying to install micropython

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I just bought a raspberry pi pico and I want to install micropython on it. but as soon as I install micropython the device ejects and when reconnect it all files are gone. it has 2 files in it(index.htm and info_uf2.txt with a lock icon on them). I tried Thonny but result was the same. I would be appreciate if you solve my problem.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `device ejects`

Comment: Isn't that normal behaviour? Copy the uf2 file and then the pico automatically restarts. Then you can add your own files / code. Have you read the docs, e.g. starting with https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html

Comment: thank you. even if I add a main.py file to it. this file would be deleted too.